# CKEditor: Button tags are not working in CKEditor 4

Tags: jquery, ckeditor4.x

We have button tags `<button type="button">Edit</button>` almost in all our forms, this tag looks fine when i use CK-Editor version 3, but now we want to upgrade to version 4.7.3. When we use our existing forms with newer version of ck-editor, button tags are displaying as plain text instead of button control. But this is working fine when i use input type button`<input type="button" />`.

Comment: share your code how are you creating the buttons

Comment: As i menstioned in above question, i am creating buttons like <button type="button">Edit</button>

Comment: add the 'button' type to allowedContent in your ckeditor config, see more here: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent

Answer (score 0):

Use strong tag inside the button tag to solve this issue,
ex: `<button><strong>text</strong><button>`